# `Dense(units=1)` output shape is not `(batch_size, 1)` as expected

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, shapes, bert-language-model

Here's a model:

```
import random
import string

import tensorflow as tf
from keras import Input, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer, TFDistilBertModel


def create_model(input_shape, cache_dir, pretrained_model):
    ids = Input(input_shape, dtype='int32', name='input_ids')
    masks = Input(input_shape, dtype='int32', name='attention_mask')
    x0 = dict(input_ids=ids, attention_mask=masks)
    x = TFDistilBertModel.from_pretrained(pretrained_model, cache_dir=cache_dir)(x0)[0]
    x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = Dense(64)(x)
    x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
    output = Dense(1, 'sigmoid')(x)
    return Model(x0, output))
```

I need the output to be of shape `(100, 1)` however, it's `(100, 512)` in this example:

```
pretrained_model = 'distilbert-base-uncased'
cache_dir = '.'
tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(
    pretrained_model, cache_dir=cache_dir
)
s = string.ascii_letters
text = [''.join(random.choice(s) for _ in range(10)) for _ in range(100)]
tokens = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
    text,
    add_special_tokens=True,
    truncation=True,
    return_tensors='np',
    padding='max_length',
)
model = create_model((None,), cache_dir, pretrained_model)
preds = model(dict(tokens))
print(preds.shape)
```

shape:

```
TensorShape([100, 512])
```

This is meant to get n tokenized sentences as input and output a score for each that will determine their order. How to achieve this using the current / other variations of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, you are returning the full vector with probabilities. If this is the case,

```
np.argmax(preds,axis=1)
```

... may solve your problem.

Comment: The dense layer is intended to get a tensor of tokens, and output a score (rank) for each sentence. Is argmax what I need in this case? The rank is intended to order the given sentences.

Comment: Are you getting `last_hidden_state` as output ?

Comment: I don't have access to my laptop right now, I'll check as soon as I do. What if I do and what if I don't?

Comment: The `np.argmax` refers to a classification problem, like the one in your first example with sigmoid activation function. However, if you are getting `last_hidden_state`, means that you created word embeddings for a given text. This last option means that you extracted the state of the last hidden layers before the output.

Comment: If I'm not missing something, I only get a tensor of shape `(100, 512)`. Not sure about where to check for `last_hidden_state`. At any case what do you suggest to get the proper shapes and orders/ranks given it's not a classification problem?